# Как выводить статьи через файл, но не указывать его в URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Сейчас я вывожу статьи через файл article.php, в htaccess стоит вот такой код:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ article.php [L]
```

Таким образом, я получаю читаемый URL вида site.ru/article/123/. 123 - id статьи

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как можно отбросить слово article в url и выводить статью через site.ru/123/, используя при этом тот же самый файл article.php?

Answer (score 1):

В своем `.htaccess` файле вы указали маршрут, что все URL по адресу `www.domain.com/articles` будут уходить в скрипт `article.php`, просто уберите `article/` из вашего правила, и добавить условие, чтобы в итоге получилось примерно такое:

```
#...
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[0-9]+)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ article.php [L]
```

Данное правило говорит серверу, что если после домена вашего сайта будет идти передача `GET` параметра в виде `www.domain.com/123` (цифр), то все запросы уйдут в скрипт `article.php`.